# Thread independentes a partir do resultado

Tags: java, thread

Tenho uma consulta onde retorna uma lista de resultados;

Exemplo:

```
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
```

Gostaria que partir dessa lista criar uma thread para cada um independentes. Para cada um fazer seu respectivo processamento.

Atualmente eu uso só que que espera um terminar para o outro processar

```
new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            MeuController mc = new MeuController();
            List lista = mc.getMetodo();
            Iterator it = lista.iterator();
            while( it.hasNext() ){
               Model model = (Model) it.next();
               //agora vai processar
            }
         }
    }.start();
```

Tem como?

Comment: E esse trecho de código está dentro de um laço de repetição? Em que momento está esperando a *thread* finalizar?

Comment: Não. Só dentro dele que tem um while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça isso:

```
new MeuController().getMetodo().forEach(model -> {
    new Thread(() -> {
        //agora vai processar
    }).start();
});
```

Ou então, você cria um método assim:

```
private void processar(Model model) {
    //agora vai processar
}
```

E então faz isso:

```
new MeuController().getMetodo().forEach(model -> {
    new Thread(() -> processar(model)).start();
});
```

Comment: Naquela primeira opção: como eu poderia ler essa linha `Model model = (Model) it.next();` no caso o it seria iterator

Comment: @adventistaam Esqueça o `Iterator`, desde o Java 5, há pouca ou nenhuma necessidade de se trabalhar com `Iterator`s diretamente, e a partir do Java 8 ainda menos. O `forEach` já cuida dos detalhes da iteração. Tudo isso supõe que o `getMetodo()` devolva uma `List<Model>`.

Comment: Hum, entendi...

Comment: @adventistaam No entanto, se a sua dúvida é só ler a linha `Model model = (Model) it.next();`, isso é porque o método `next` puxará o próximo item a ser iterado de dentro do `Iterator` que percorre o `List`. Idealmente, tanto o `List` quanto o `Iterator` deveriam ser genéricos, de forma que o `List<Model>` cria um `Iterator<Model>` o que faz com que o tipo de retorno do método `next()` seja um `Model`, que é atribuído a variável `model`. No entanto, como o `List` e o `Iterator` estão sem o tipo genérico, o compilador enxerga `Object` como retorno do `next()`, e portanto aí precisa de um cast.